# Change components with ajax. (Ractivejs)

Tags: ractivejs

```
views.list = Ractive.extend({/*...*/});

var Content = Ractive.extend({
    template: '#template-content',
    components: {
        //view: views['list']
    },
    onrender: function() {
        /* call this.request */
    },
    request: function(route) {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: route,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                self.components.view = views[data.view];
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Ajax request returns {view:'list'}. I write in the console: "Content.components.view" and see:

```
function ( options ) {
    initialise( this, options );
}
```

But "Content.findComponent('view')" returns "null".

It will work if I uncomment the line "//view: views['list']" in the components. How to dynamically change the component?

**Update 1:**

I thought I can do this:

```
var Content = Ractive.extend({
    components: {
        // Aaaand add listener for data.view?
        view: function(data) {
            return views[data.view];
            // But no, it is not updated when changes data.view ...
        }
    },
    data: {},
    oninit: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.set('view', 'list');
    },
});
```

Not work.. Why then need "data" argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won :)

```
// Create component globally
Ractive.components.ListView = Ractive.extend({});

// Create ractive instance
var Content = Ractive.extend({
    template: '#template-content',
    partials: {
        view: 'Loading...' // So... default
    },
    oninit: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data){
                // Hardcore inject component
                self.partials.view = '<'+data.view+'/>';

                // Little hack for update partial in template
                self.set('toggle', true);
                self.set('toggle', false);
            }
        });
    },
});
```

In Content template:

```
{{^toggle}}{{>view}}{{/}}
```

It's works-fireworks!